# Ski touring in Iceland

Tags: iceland, skiing

We (group of 4) are from Switzerland and want to go to Iceland the first two weeks of April 2017.

Our primary goal is to go **backcountry skiing (walk up with skins on the skis, then ski down)**. We're explicitly not looking for ski resorts.

We already know about the [Troll peninsula](http://www.visittrollaskagi.is/), because guided groups from Switzerland always go there. So we thought about going there too, because we're sure it has nice routes and beautiful scenery. But maybe there are other equally nice ski touring spots that are less known?

**Which regions in Iceland offer nice backcountry ski routes and have enough hills/mountains to stay a few days in the respective region?**

Comment: "crowded" is a relative term.  For an activity like this in a remote part of Iceland, a "crowded" area might mean no more than there is a chance someone finds you if you have a serious accident...

Comment: Agreed. When I say crowded here I mean "where the professional tour operators go".

Comment: I just mean that even a well-known area for this activity might not be noticeably crowded...and travelling in a less known area might involve considerable risk.

Comment: I understand. We are experienced backcountry skiers, so the less known areas are **exactly** what we're looking for. The lonelier the better! And yes, we know that there is a higher risk in case we have an accident, this is part of the game. Risk management is an integral part in these kinds of journeys.

Answer (score 3):

There are 11 ski resorts in Iceland and all are listed [here](http://www.skiresort.info/ski-resorts/iceland/) together with a map and other details.

Bláfjöll
Hlíðarfjall – Akureyri
Skálafell
Isafjördur
Oddsskarð
Skarðsdalur – Siglufjörður
Stafdalur
Dalvík
Tindastóll – Sauðárkrókur
Tindaöxl – Ólafsfjörður
Húsavík

Comment: Sorry maybe my question was not clear enough, we're looking for back-country skiing spots, not ski resorts. I updated my question to clarify this.

Comment: use the report as a good starting point for your skiing.